# How to derive from scratch the identities $\sin^2x=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$, $\cos^2x=\frac1{1 + t^2}$, $\sin x\cos x=\frac{t}{1+t^2}$, where $t=\tan x$?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am currently working on evaluating the integral:

$$ \int \frac{\sin x \cos x}{1 + \sin^4 x} \, dx. $$

In order to simplify the integrand, I've considered the substitution $ \tan(x) = t $.

In my textbook, I found the following trigonometric identities:

$$ \sin^2(x) = \frac{t^2}{1 + t^2}, $$
$$ \cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{1 + t^2}, $$
$$ \sin(x)\cos(x) = \frac{t}{1 + t^2}, $$ where $t=\tan(x)$.

While I can verify these identities by myself, my question pertains to how I would derive these identities without prior knowledge of their right-hand sides. Essentially, given only the idea to express them in terms of $ \tan(x) $, how would I approach deriving these identities from scratch?

I mean in this problem I would need $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$. How do I start just knowing that I have to find them in terms of $\tan(x)$.

Thank you for any insights or explanations you can provide!

Comment: While the path you have chosen is viable, it may be valuable to consider an alternate path such as $u=\sin x$ or even $u=\sin^2 x$ as well.

Comment: $t=\tan(x) = \sin(x) / \cos(x) \implies t^2 = \sin^2(x) / \cos^2(x) = \sin^2(x)/(1-\sin^2(x))$, which you can solve for $\sin^2(x)$. The others follow similarly.

Comment: @abiessu Or $u=\cos2x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $t=\tan x$, then\begin{align}t^2&=\tan^2x\\&=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}\\&=\frac{\sin^2x}{1-\sin^2x},\end{align}and therefore$$\sin^2x=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\label{a}\tag1$$On the other hand, since $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$, it follows from \eqref{a} that$$\cos^2x=\frac1{1+t^2}.$$Finally\begin{align}\sin(x)\cos(x)&=\tan(x)\cos^2(x)\\&=\frac t{1+t^2}.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\tan^2(x)}{\tan^2(x)+1}=\frac{\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}{\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}+\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}=\sin^2(x)$$
$$\frac{1}{\tan^2(x)+1}=\frac{1}{\sec^2(x)}=\cos^2(x)$$
$$\sin(x)\cos(x)=\tan(x)\cos^2(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{\tan^2(x)+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

While the rigorous way is as José stated, the way to remember these is to simply remember it as looking at the right-angled triangle with perpendicular feet $1,t$ and $\tan(x) = t$, in which case the squares of the sides are clearly $1,t^2,1+t^2$ and you get $\sin(x)^2,\cos(x)^2$ immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to approach it.

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\cos(2x) = \frac{\cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)}{\cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x)} = \frac{1 - \tan^{2}(x)}{1 + \tan^{2}(x)} \Rightarrow \sin^{2}(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2} = \frac{1}{1 + \tan^{2}(x)}
\end{align*}
Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
\cos^{2}(x) = 1 - \sin^{2}(x) = \frac{\tan^{2}(x)}{1 + \tan^{2}(x)}
\end{align*}

Finally, the last identity holds because
\begin{align*}
\sin(x)\cos(x) = \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x)} = \frac{\tan(x)}{1 + \tan^{2}(x)}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

**BONUS**

Alternatively, you can solve the proposed integral as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1 + \sin^{4}(x)}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{\sin(x)}{1 + \sin^{4}(x)}\mathrm{d}(\sin(x))\\\\
& = \int\frac{u}{1 + u^{4}}\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(u^{2})}{1 + (u^{2})^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{1 + v^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\arctan(v) + C\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\arctan(u^{2}) + C\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\arctan(\sin^{2}(x)) + C.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Consider the cartesian equation of the unit circle.

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$

And a line through the origin.

$y = tx$

And find where this intersects the circle

The slope of this line $t$ equals the tangent of the central angle.

$t = \tan \theta\\
x = \cos \theta\\
y = \sin \theta$

$x^2 + (tx)^2 = 1\\
x^2 = \frac {1}{1+t^2}\\
y^2 = (tx)^2 = \frac {t^2}{1+t^2}\\
xy = \sqrt {\left(\frac {1}{1+t^2}\right)\left(\frac {t^2}{1+t^2}\right)} = \frac {t}{1+t^2}$

A similar trick using the line can be used to derive the implications of the $t = \tan \frac {\theta}{2}$ substitution.